Scenario Outline gherkin steps parameter set up
In the feature file, Scenario Outline, eg, 

When user enters "<userName>"

Examples:

|userName|
|xxxx|


The question is that I see sometimes placing the place holder userName inside "<>" and other times without double quotes <>. I watched some you tubers and as usual, everyone just type and go. any difference? if it has to do passing strings or numbers?
couldn't apply to the application am testing
This format requirement is wasting my time. I should be able to post in any way and someone who can help...

Scenario Outlines are syntactic sugar for repeating the scenario a bunch of times. So for example if you have
Feature: Examples Tables

  Scenario Outline: Eating cucumbers
    Given there are "<start>" cucumbers
    When I eat <eat> cucumbers
    Then I should have <left> cucumbers

    Examples: These are passing
      | start  | eat | left |
      | twelve |   5 |    7 |
      | twenty |   5 |   15 |

That could also be written as
Feature: Examples Tables

  Scenario: Eating cucumbers
    Given there are "twelve" cucumbers
    When I eat 5 cucumbers
    Then I should have 7 cucumbers

  Scenario: Eating cucumbers
    Given there are "twenty" cucumbers
    When I eat 5 cucumbers
    Then I should have 15 cucumbers

So it doesn't matter if you use "<..>" or just <..>. The contents between the angle brackets gets replaced.
Where it does matter is your step definitions. These could be
@Given("^there are \"(.*)\" cucumbers$")
@When("^I eat (.*) cucumbers$")

When the " are part of the step, they must also be included in the step definition.
Or if you are using Cucumber expressions:
@Given("there are {string} cucumbers")
@When("I eat {int} cucumbers")

Then {string} assumes that there are " on both sides of the parameter being matched.
edit:
I did see you're using Behave. I'm not 100% if it works exactly the same as Cucumber-JS, Cucumber-Java, ect, but it is probably close enough.

Thank you for your time and insight. But mine is Behave and still not getting it fixed. still throwing assertion error like expected t = {str} ' "xxx" ' actual t = {str} 'xxx' . The question is that the former onw has '' single and quotes while the later only gets single quote.

Hard to say. You'd have to show me what exactly you're doing

At a glance though it looks like the ' are part of the message. So the expected value is "xxx" (a string with quote characters) while the expected is xxx (a string without quotes). It might also be that you got the values in your assertion the wrong way around, but again, hard to say.

In my research what I noticed is that most of the contributors no/limited knowledge of Behave-Python stuff. Millions of people posting on Cucumber but little on behave.

Don't @ in JavaScript. Given("there are {string} cucumbers", async function (string){...})

Now resolved> What I learned is that if the values passed to the parameters are constants, only <> should be applied not with double quotes like "<>"
